# Highchart area chart with date time

Tags: php, charts, highcharts, stacked-area-chart

In the highchart area chart I have to add date in x axis and punch in time in y axis. Its for the punch in time a student in a month. So it have n number of date time values and represent it in area chart. How the date and time used in area chart? Its my code.

```js
Highcharts.chart('batch_range_chart', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Time (hh:mm)'
    },
    type: 'datetime',

  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Date'
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      //month: '%b \'%y',
    }

  },

  tooltip: {

    //pointFormat: '{series.name} Check In Time <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {

    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Check In Time',
    data: [
      [1514831400, 10: 00: 00],
      [1514917800, 14: 30: 00],
      [1515004200, 11: 00: 00],
      [1515090600, 09: 00: 00]
    ],
    color: '#6767af'

  }, ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="batch_range_chart" style="min-width:100%; height: 280px; margin: 0 auto">
  </div>
```

Its the graph

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, and not understandable. Please describe your problem and ask a question more precisely, then we would be able to help you much better.

Answer (score 1):

**For Date**: You can put the date as `Date.UTC(2018, 10, 15)` 
**For Time** It one numeric value which you can calculate on the basis of seconds,minutes,or miliseconds for showing on the graph.

yAxis formatter you can keep as:

```
formatter: function() {
          var time = this.value;
          var hours1 = parseInt(time / 60);
          var mins1 = parseInt(parseInt(time % 60));
          return hours1 + ':' + mins1;
        }
```

In the above formatter, its calculating the hours and minutes based on total number of minutes. e.g 100 min = 1:40AM

```js
function minutesToHHMM (mins, twentyFour = false) {
  let h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  let m = mins % 60;
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;

  if (twentyFour) {
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    return `${h}:${m}`;
  } else {
    let a = 'am';
    if (h >= 12) a = 'pm';
    if (h > 12) h = h - 12;
    return `${h}:${m} ${a}`;
  }
}



$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%e of %b'
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Time (hh:mm)'
      },
      max: 1440,
      tickInterval: 10,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          var time = this.value;
          return minutesToHHMM(time);
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      },
   },
    series: [{
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2018, 10, 15), 1440],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 10, 16), 200],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 10, 17), 300],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 10, 18), 0]
      ]

    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: How we can handle the time 12am and 12pm? In database 12am stored as 00:00:00, but it listed in the 12pm area of chart.

Comment: I have added a method to change add AM/PM to chart. please check

Comment: How we can add another color after a particular time? I mean dual color on same column?